# Maintain Composition Root when creating components in a Parallel.Foreach loop (threading)

Tags: multithreading, autofac

I'm trying to learn the correct way inside a Parallel ForEach loop to not reference composition root yet create a thread component based on the component referenced in the composition root.

This is the composition root code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<OperationFiscalCalendarSql>().As<IOperationCloser>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<SQLMessagePoller>().As<IMessagePoller>().SingleInstance();
...
var container = builder.Build();
using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
...
}
```

and this is the code that is referenced in the poller object that has the foreach loop:

```
Parallel.ForEach(messageHeaders, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _maxDegreeOfParallelism }, messageHeader => {
    ...
    var sapCloser = new OperationFiscalCalendarSql(closeObj, repostiory);
    ...                        
});
```

Note I want an instance of IOperationCloser instead of hardcoding a 'new'ed up OperationFiscalCalendarSql object.

I understand constructor injection I just don't know how to inject an IOperationCloser when it is in any kind of loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a factory in your `Poller` object with `Func<IOperationCloser>` and then get a new instance in the `ForEach` loop.

In your case it may be even better to create your own `ILifetimeScope`. You can do this by injecting `ILieetimeScope` in `Poller` and then call `BeginLifetimeScope` and `Resolve` in the loop.

```
Parallel.ForEach(messageHeaders, ..., m => {
    using(ILifetimeScope childScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope()){
        var param1 = new TypedParameter(m);
        var closer = childScope.Resolve<IOperationCloser>(param1);
    });
});
```